# Bind vectors across lists to single list of matrices

Tags: r, list

I'd like to join multiple vectors across separate lists and output a single list of matrices. The idea is that all items of the list with the same name, for example all the `a` items, are joined by rows as a matrix. The added complication is that these vectors can be of different lengths, so `rbind` is not straightforward to implement; the missing values in the matrix can be appended with `NA`s.

#### Example

Input lists:

```r
list1 <- list(a = 1:5, b = 6:10, c = 11:15)
list2 <- list(a = 1:4, b = 6:9, c = 11:14)
list3 <- list(a = 1:3, b = 6:8, c = 11:13)

list1
# $a
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
# 
# $b
# [1]  6  7  8  9 10
# 
# $c
# [1] 11 12 13 14 15
#
```

The desired output I'm hoping to obtain is a list with as many matrices as there are unique list items, where each matrix consists of the vectors of differing lengths bound by rows:

```r
# $a
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    2    3    4    5
# [2,]    1    2    3    4   NA
# [3,]    1    2    3   NA   NA
# 
# $b
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    6    7    8    9   10
# [2,]    6    7    8    9   NA
# [3,]    6    7    8   NA   NA
# 
# $c
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]   11   12   13   14   15
# [2,]   11   12   13   14   NA
# [3,]   11   12   13   NA   NA
```

How would I go about writing a function that does this that also scales up to merging longer lists with vectors of varying lengths?

Comment: Are the lists (i.e. `list1` etc) going to have the same names in the same order?

Comment: Unfortunately no, the names could be anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to `transpose` the `list` of `list`s, then `reduce` the `list` elements to a single dataset with `cbind.fill`, get the transpose (`t`) and assign the row names to `NULL`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rowr)
list(list1, list2, list3) %>% 
    transpose %>% 
    map(~ reduce(.x, cbind.fill, fill = NA) %>% 
          t %>% 
         `row.names<-`(NULL))
#$a
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
#[2,]    1    2    3    4   NA
#[3,]    1    2    3   NA   NA

#$b
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    6    7    8    9   10
#[2,]    6    7    8    9   NA
#[3,]    6    7    8   NA   NA

#$c
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]   11   12   13   14   15
#[2,]   11   12   13   14   NA
#[3,]   11   12   13   NA   NA
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
do.call(Map, c(f = function(...) {l1 <- list(...)
   do.call(rbind, lapply(l1, `length<-`, max(lengths(l1))))},  
      mget(paste0("list", 1:3))))
```

Comment: I've been trying to go down this path: ```list(list1, list2, list3) %>% 
  do.call("rbind", .) %>% 
  transform``` but I am stuck. Any insights?

Comment: @M-M You can do this in another way with `do.call(Map, c(f = function(...) {l1 <- list(...); do.call(rbind, lapply(l1, `length<-`, max(lengths(l1))))},  mget(paste0("list", 1:3))))`

Comment: @akrun Thanks. It turned out to be an inefficient solution but your comment, specifically this part: ```lapply(l1, `length<-`, max(lengths(l1)))``` helped a lot.

Answer (score 4):

a `data.table` solution, just for fun:

```
plouf <- list(list1,list2,list3)

lapply(names(list1),function(name){
  lapply(plouf,function(x){
     as.data.table(t(x[[name]]))
     }) %>% 
    rbindlist(.,fill =T) %>%
`colnames<-`(NULL)
}) %>% setNames(names(list1))


$a

1:  1  2  3  4  5
2:  1  2  3  4 NA
3:  1  2  3 NA NA

$b

1:  6  7  8  9 10
2:  6  7  8  9 NA
3:  6  7  8 NA NA

$c

1: 11 12 13 14 15
2: 11 12 13 14 NA
3: 11 12 13 NA NA
```

the first loop is on the list name. The second loop loop is on the list of list, and extract the element of each list, transpose it into a data.table with unique row, to be able to use `rbindlist` which can fill missing columns.

without `data.table`, so similar but less good than what akrun proposed:

```
library(plyr)

lapply(names(list1),function(name){
  lapply(plouf,function(x){
    t(x[[name]])%>%
      as.data.frame
  }) %>% 
   rbind.fill %>%
    `colnames<-`(NULL)
}) %>% setNames(names(list1))
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use **1.** `rapply` to adjust the `length`s of the sublists, and **2.** `t(mapply)` to get the matrices by selecting with `'[['`.

```
listn <- list(list1, list2, list3)

setNames(lapply(seq(listn), function(x) 
  t(mapply(`[[`, rapply(listn, `length<-`, value=5, how="list"), x))), names(el(listn)))
# $a
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    2    3    4    5
# [2,]    1    2    3    4   NA
# [3,]    1    2    3   NA   NA
# 
# $b
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    6    7    8    9   10
# [2,]    6    7    8    9   NA
# [3,]    6    7    8   NA   NA
# 
# $c
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]   11   12   13   14   15
# [2,]   11   12   13   14   NA
# [3,]   11   12   13   NA   NA
```

In case the lengths are unknown use this code:

```
max(rapply(listn, length))
# [1] 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a doodle of mine:

```
library(magrittr)
```

```r
list(list1, list2, list3) %>% 
  do.call("rbind", .) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  sapply(., function(x) lapply(x, `length<-`, max(lengths(x)))) %>% 
  apply(., 2, as.list) %>% 
  lapply(., function(x) do.call(rbind, x))
```

```r
# $a
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    2    3    4    5
# [2,]    1    2    3    4   NA
# [3,]    1    2    3   NA   NA
# 
# $b
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    6    7    8    9   10
# [2,]    6    7    8    9   NA
# [3,]    6    7    8   NA   NA
# 
# $c
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]   11   12   13   14   15
# [2,]   11   12   13   14   NA
# [3,]   11   12   13   NA   NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Using base R, we can concatenate all the lists together at same level (`list_df`). Loop through `unique` names in `list_df` and subset them and create a list of matrices of similar named elements.

```
list_df <- c(list1, list2, list3)

lapply(unique(names(list_df)), function(x) {
     temp <- list_df[names(list_df) == x]
     t(sapply(temp, `[`, seq_len(max(lengths(temp)))))
})

#[[1]]
#  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#a    1    2    3    4    5
#a    1    2    3    4   NA
#a    1    2    3   NA   NA

#[[2]]
#  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#b    6    7    8    9   10
#b    6    7    8    9   NA
#b    6    7    8   NA   NA

#[[3]]
#  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#c   11   12   13   14   15
#c   11   12   13   14   NA
#c   11   12   13   NA   NA
```